# Meta Programming Functions And Tests

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

First, I have a module which defines user roles and validations for my user model:

```
defmodule ClubHomepage.Web.UserRole do

  ...

  @roles %{
    "administrator": "user with all rights",
    "member": "a registered user",
    "match-editor": "editor of matches and reporter of live match events",
    "news-editor": "author/editor of news",
    "player": "an active sports man/woman",
    "team-editor": "right to edit teams",
    "text-page-editor": "author/editor of static page contents",
    "user-editor": "user administrator"
  }

  @spec defined_roles_keys() :: [String.t]
  def defined_roles_keys do
    Map.keys(@roles)
    |> Enum.map(fn(role) -> Atom.to_string(role) end)
  end

  ...

end
```

Than, I have a module, that defines plug functions generated from the keys of the former defined user roles:

```
defmodule ClubHomepage.Web.AuthByRole do

  ...

  @spec plug_function_name(String.t) :: Atom.t
  def plug_function_name(user_role_key) do
    "is_#{String.replace(user_role_key, "-", "_")}"
    |> String.to_atom()
  end

  for user_role_key <- UserRole.defined_roles_keys() do
    function_name = plug_function_name(user_role_key)

    @spec unquote(function_name)(Plug.Conn.t, Keyword.t) :: Boolean
    def unquote(function_name)(conn, _options) do
      has_role(conn, unquote(user_role_key))
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

**Problem 1:** I extracted some code from the for comprehension into the function `plug_function_name`. But after I get an error:

```
== Compilation error on file lib/club_homepage/web/commands/auth_by_role.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/club_homepage/web/commands/auth_by_role.ex:31: undefined function plug_function_name/1
```

**How can I do that in a better way but to keep my code dry?**

My intension here is to use `plug_function_name` within my test module to generate the same function names and to call the generated plug functions in the tests:

```
defmodule ClubHomepage.Web.AuthByRoleTest do
  use ClubHomepage.Web.ConnCase

  alias ClubHomepage.Web.UserRole
  alias ClubHomepage.Web.AuthByRole

  setup do
    conn =
      build_conn()
      |> bypass_through(ClubHomepage.Web.Router, :browser)
      |> get("/")
    {:ok, %{conn: conn}}
  end

  for user_role_key <- UserRole.defined_roles_keys() do
    function_name = AuthByRole.plug_function_name(user_role_key)

    test "#{function_name} halts when no current_user exists", %{conn: conn} do
      conn = AuthByRole.is_administrator(conn, [])
      assert flash_messages_contain?(conn, "You are not authorized to view this page.")
      assert conn.halted
    end

    test "#{function_name} continues when the current_user has the #{user_role_key} role", %{conn: conn} do
      conn =
        conn
        |> assign(:current_user, %ClubHomepage.User{roles: "member #{user_role_key}"})
        |> AuthByRole.is_administrator([])
      refute conn.halted
    end
  end
end
```

**Problem 2:** Within the generated tests I need to replace the calls to `AuthByRole.is_administrator(conn, [])` with `AuthByRole.`**function_name**`(conn, [])`.

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem, you'll need to define the function you want to call at compile time in a separate module so that the Elixir compiler compiles that module first and makes it available to the main module when the main module is being compiled. Here's an example you can adapt:

```
defmodule M.Helper do
  def function_name(x), do: :"#{x}#{x}"
end

defmodule M do
  import M.Helper

  for x <- ~w(a b c) do
    name = function_name(x)
    def unquote(name)(), do: unquote(name)
  end
end
```

```
iex(1)> M.aa
:aa
iex(2)> M.bb
:bb
iex(3)> M.cc
:cc
```

For the second problem, you can use `AuthByRole.unquote(function_name)(conn, [])`. Here's an example:

```
defmodule MTest do
  use ExUnit.Case
  import M.Helper

  for x <- ~w(a b c) do
    name = function_name(x)
    test name do
      assert M.unquote(name) == unquote(name)
    end
  end
end
```

```
$  m mix test --trace

MTest
  * test aa (1.2ms)
  * test cc (0.00ms)
  * test bb (0.00ms)


Finished in 0.02 seconds
3 tests, 0 failures
```

Comment: Both problems are solved. Well done, great job. You saved my day. Why works `AuthByRole.unquote(function_name)(conn, [])`? I have no unquote function in my module by an import or so. Is it because `test` is a macro?

Comment: `unquote` is https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#unquote/1. Yes, as far as I know, `unquote` works because `test` is a macro. The same thing also works with `def` (which is also a macro), for example: `defmodule A do; name = :inspect; def a do; IO.unquote(name)(:hi); end; end`.